# Which of these the best way to make my page responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have designed 3 versions of a web page - desktop, tablet and mobile.

Content is same but layout is different.

Which approach is best to convert the page to responsive html:

a) Separate html files

b) Separate CSS files

c) Single CSS file

You can view jpegs of the 3 versions here:

```
Desktop: 
shrineweb.in/other-files/clients/showyourskills/test/Home.jpg
Tablet: 
shrineweb.in/other-files/clients/showyourskills/test/Home-tablet.jpg
Mobile: 
shrineweb.in/other-files/clients/showyourskills/test/Home-mobile.jpg
```

How can i do this ?

**Note : Mobile version's navigation (top-right) is different from Tablet and Desktop version.**

Comment: It's possible to manipulate the menu using CSS only. No need for different HTML. For example, see [bootstrap navigation example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use separate css files with media queries. But there are ready made solutions available, so it is more convenient to use them rather than inventing the wheel from scratch. You can use Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation for responsive web designs.

Answer (score 0):

Separate CSS files would be clearer and easier.

Maybe you can [click here](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries) to read more about responsive design and how to begin writing the different CSS media queries for each responsive layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single css file and add the layout for different versions using mediaquery and bootstrap...